# Parse trigonometric function without evaluation or simplification

Tags: python, sympy

In sympy, I can parse a simple term with
`sympy.parse_expr("1 * (x+0)", evaluate=False)` and get the expected output `1*(x + 0)`.

However, if I my input contains a trigonometric function like `sympy.parse_expr("sin(pi)", evaluate=False)` the output is 0. Thus, it is evaluated, although it shouldn't.

How can I pass such a string to sympy and don't get it evaluated, like in the first example?

Comment: to be sure to understand your problem, what would be the output you would expect from `sympy.parse_expr("sin(pi)", evaluate=False)` ?

Comment: It should be "sin(pi)", but as a sympy object, not a string. If I pass ```sin(1)``` I get a sin object back.

Comment: I haven't used sympy in ages but irrc, but in this case, shouldn't you first assign `sin(x)` as an expression? I might be wrong!

Comment: why don't you want to evaluate it ? What's your use case ?

Comment: @dallonsi I just want the symbolic representation for further manipulation and/or printing (Latex, etc.)

Comment: @limes if you just want to print it later, use this trick: sympy.parse_expr("sin(Pi)", evaluate=False) with an uppercase P for Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parsing can give greater non-evauation in an `evaluate(False)` context:

```
>>> with evaluate(False):
...   eq = S(sin(pi))
...
>>> eq
sin(pi)
```